# Detect when iOS device wakes up from sleep

Tags: ios, locking, screen, device

Is there anyway I can detect when the device wakes up? By sleep I mean device with the screen off, and by wakes up I mean when the device's screen is on or when lock screen is showed (when home or power button is pressed). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can detect when your app stops being the active application with:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

in the app delegate.

Also, you can detect when it comes back into view with:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

There isn't a way to detect that the device was locked vs detecting if the user switched from your app to another app. All you can know is that the user is leaving your app and you can know when they've returned to your app.

Comment: There is `applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable` and `applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable` and `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable` on the AppDelegate. They report lock status using public APIs. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623044-applicationprotecteddatadidbecom